# How to protect a crypto currency from Seed failure

Tags: security, seed, cryptonote

I have created a new currency based on Forknote/Cryptnote.

It has a small number of Seed Nodes.

I am investigating how to mitigate the risks of currency failure due to Seed Node collapse from

- Legislation forcing hosting providers to no longer allow Seed Nodes
- A synchronized server attack.

Is the only way to mitigate this to have multiple Seed Nodes in multiple locations by multiple providers? Or is there any way I can rely on continuing to have a small number of Seed Nodes but rely on the distributed nature of local copies on the blockchain on mining machines?